# Where can you find the control panel for xampp in mac?

Tags: macos, xampp, control-panel

This seems like a very basic question, but I can't seem to find a straightforward answer online after searching for very long.

I am using xampp, but can't seem to find the control panel.

The only application I have is manager-osx

Is there something missing in my download? Or is there a procedure to run the control panel?

[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: I am not sure if I just can't see the control panel just because I am using mac.

Comment: The xampp control on a mac is called manager-osx, it seems right but you can search here https://www.apachefriends.org/faq_osx.html maybe you can find something.

Comment: Thank you for the link! Yes, I have been able to work with the manager-osx perfectly fine. I was just really confused because I was following tutorials where they used the Windows control panel. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked up the question on the apache forum for mac and it appears there the interface you're looking for is only available on Windows.

Answer (score 14):

Yeah, thanks @Jon's answer helped me out in the end, indirectly.
They should make a cross platform with Electron, it's 2018 already! :).

But you can pick the `Manage Servers` tab and have similar functionality on MAC:

[image: XAMPP Control Panel - Called Manager OSX]

I find it most annoying that the Xampp manager doesn't have `XAMPP` in the name, but is vaguely called 'manager-osx'. This way you can't quickly find it through OS X's Spotlight search. The names comes across as a bit of egocentric of the developers thinking they've made only manager application. But yeah; it's freeware...

Answer (score 8):

MANAGER-OSX LAUNCH THE CONTROL PANEL IN MAC OSX

XAMPP V7.2.0-0

ROUTE: aplications/XAMMP/xampfiles/manager-osx

Please refer to the screenshot below

[image: Check this screenshot for reference]

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for, it wasn't showing up in the spotlight search. It's the same for version 5.x if anyone else is wondering.

Answer (score 3):

Only way to open control panel is :

Step 1 : Open manager- osx

Step 2 : Choose Manage Servers

Step 3 : Turn all Servers on i.e - Mysql Database, ProFTPD & Apache Web
Server.
All Servers should be running

Step 4 : Go To browser & Open below given link --------

```
     http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

After this Control Panel will open.

Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

There is no Control panel as much as Windows. you have to go to the route. usually its Finder > Applications > (find your Xampp Folder) > Expand the folder. that's the current way and its helped me with android studios